# List of <li> elements without javascript

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have a problem with show dropdown menu in mobile (small display) version in responsive design webpage (using css3 with flexbox)

I have a 11 `<li>` element. The first element is just show menu button and 10 next elements with quests. In classic web version I'm not showing the "Menu" button, only the quests. But in mobile version I'm showing just "Menu" button and I want show quests after *hover* or *click* on this button (rather click) without javascirpt. It is possible please? I'm jusing css3 flexbox with `li:first-child {display:none;}` in classic version and `li {display:none;} li:first-child {display:block;}` in mobile version.

*HTML*

```html
<nav class="menu">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-menu"></i>Menu</a></li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">1. A mystery to begin with</a></li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">2. Running out of water!</a></li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">3. A message from Sir Cogwheel</a></li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">4. The treasure hunt</a></li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>5. A dangerous drink</li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>6. Think, think, think, …</li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>7. Keep your eyes open</li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">8. A safe deposit</a></li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">9. The preparation</a></li>
                    <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">10. Get him!</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

*CSS*

```css
ul {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /*--This is basic setting, we can ignore it later. It's just tu show different between column and row */
}

li {
    background-color: #555;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #aaa;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    width: 17em;
}

li:first-child {
    display: none;
    color:white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
   .menu {
        display: inline-block;
        flex: 1;
    }

    ul {        
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    li {
        display: none;
    }

    li:first-child {
        display: inline-block;
        flex: 1;
    }

    li:first-child:hover li {
            background-color: red;
            display: block;
    }
}
```

All code you can see here: https://codepen.io/oslicek/pen/VJJVZE?editors=1111

Nothing to do with li elements after `li:first-child:hover` in mobile version

Thanks for any advice

Comment: This is better achieved with javascript. It is possible without but involves adding a hidden checkbox, changing the Menu link to a `label` and then using the `:checked` pseudo class with a sibling selector. And having just looked deeper, it would require a fairly major refactoring of your HTML

Comment: Better if you do this with JavaScript. It's more complicated when you try to do by only css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

I think that beast solution is add `checkbox` and then `label` for that checkbox which can be button. Afterward, you can show menu via **CSS**

```html
    <header>
        <h1>Mystery Game</h1>
        <label for="menu-checkbox" class="menu-button">Menu</label>
        <nav>   
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html#">1. Start here</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">2. Running out of the water</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">3. Think about this</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">4. Can you solve consite puzzle?</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">5. Wrong way!</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">6. Are you scared about dark?</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">7. Light at the end of the tunnel</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">8. You are so close... but...</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">9. Bullying</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html#">10. Final Form</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

And then in css add action for this Show the menu with css animation

```css
    /* At first, we show the menu button */
    .menu-button {
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul {
        border-radius: 0.5em; /* Just a bit rounded borders for better look */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92); /* A small transparency of black color for menu */
        position: fixed; /* Fixed position is important for hide the menu */
        top: 100px; /* This value should be more than 0 otherwise you can cover your header with menu button :) The value depens how height header you have */
        left: -100%; /* This is important for make an animation */
        width: calc(100% - 15pt); /* Set up your menu width as you want but be beware of scrollbalrs */
        height: calc(100vh - 10vh); /* Height could be 100vh if you want cover whole page */
        transition: all .5s; /* Animation will take 0.5 second */
    }

    /* Now we display whole menu, but it's hidden because menu has fixed position with -100% from left */
    nav li {
        display: block;
    }

    #menu-checkbox:checked ~ ul  {
        left: 10px; /* After click menu will be placed width like 10px margin */
    }
```

**Don't forget!** This is very important to combine with media query like

```css
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      /* Here should be a code above */
    }
```

At first, you should programming mobile device first thigs, so, the reason is this is not ideal solution but works very well (but you have device desktop first) header and editing behavior menu if you has small display :/

*Can anyonve advice better solution with mobile-first coding?*

But hopefully this solution can help to many people

Answer (score 1):

This is only proof of concept, so the appearance is secondary;) Unfortunately, in order to be able to do it in css, you had to slightly modify the html.

```css
html {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
  height: 5em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
}

footer {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  display: flex;
  height: 32px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /*--This is basic setting, we can ignore it later. It's just tu show different between column and row */
}

li {
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 17em;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #06a;
}

img {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524654458049-e36be0721fa2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.news-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.news-block:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.news-picture {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
}

.news-date {
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.news-description {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 1.2em;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
  color: black;
}

.mdi {
  padding-right: 0.3em;
}

#menu-button {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .content {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .menu-button {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .checkbox label {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#menu {
    display: block;
  }
  li:first-child:hover li {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <h1>Mysterious Game</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <nav class="menu">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-button">
        <label for="menu-button">Menu</label>
        <ul id="menu">
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">1. A mystery to begin with</a></li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">2. Running out of water!</a></li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">3. A message from Sir Cogwheel</a></li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">4. The treasure hunt</a></li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>5. A dangerous drink</li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>6. Think, think, think, …</li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>7. Keep your eyes open</li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">8. A safe deposit</a></li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">9. The preparation</a></li>
          <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">10. Get him!</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <article class="article">
      <div class="news">
        <div class="news-block">
          <div class="news-picture">
            <img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/61ee19e9fbdf3cdc26914a55913ca589/tumblr_pnt0xjw4WE1s2brnwo1_640.jpg" alt="news-picture" width="150">
          </div>
          <div class="news-date">19.06.2019</div>
          <div class="news-description">
            Register you fursuit today!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-block">
          <div class="news-picture">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CnVspVNW8AUjSDh.jpg" alt="news-picture" width="150">
          </div>
          <div class="news-date">17.06.2019</div>
          <div class="news-description">
            Registration will be opened so quickly. Please stay tuned!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    Footer of webpage
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add the hover event to the `ul` element

```
ul:hover li{ /* show all lists items */
    display: block;
}
ul:hover li:first-of-type{ /* except the first one */
    display: none;
}
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /*--This is basic setting, we can ignore it later. It's just tu show different between column and row */
 }

 li {
  background-color: #555;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #aaa;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
  margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 17em;
 }

 li:first-child {
  display: none;
  color:white;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .menu {
   display: inline-block;
   flex: 1;
  }

  ul {
   flex-direction: row;
      display: block;
      float: left;
  }

  li {
   display: none;
  }

  li:first-child {
   display: inline-block;
   flex: 1;
  }

  li:first-child:hover li{
   background-color: red;
   display: block;
  }

  ul:hover li{
   display: block;
  }
  ul:hover li:first-of-type{
   display: none;
  }
 }
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-menu"></i>Menu</a></li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">1. A mystery to begin with</a></li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">2. Running out of water!</a></li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">3. A message from Sir Cogwheel</a></li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">4. The treasure hunt</a></li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>5. A dangerous drink</li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>6. Think, think, think, …</li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock"></i>7. Keep your eyes open</li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">8. A safe deposit</a></li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">9. The preparation</a></li>
  <li><i class="mdi mdi-lock-open"></i><a href="#">10. Get him!</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sure. But this doesn't solve a problem to show only first element on mobile devices and show menu without javascript after click :)